# mount samba share on a vmware instance

Tags: linux, ssh, java, snmp

I've a windows machine in which a linux server is run by a "VMWare player". From the windows machine, I want some folders to be mounted on the Linux virtual server. All this is done in a maven build (which is quite irrevelant here, in fact). From what I understand, to make these windows folders available as mountable ones, I have to do the following operations

1. Share the folders as Samba ones using net share, this I have done.
2. Access my virtual server and check which folders are already mounted (which seems to be doable using a `less /etc/fstab`), this I'll do soon
3. Mount my samba shares using `smbmount`

All that seems to my by far too hackish code. Could the same be done using ... say ... JMX/SNMP or any other high-level technology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you will have added your samba shares to be mounted at boot (using the declaration in /etc/fstab), there won't be anything to do each time you launch the VM to access the shared drives. How is that hackish? It's configuration and set up :)

You'll spend way more time and energy trying to run around a more convenient way to set it up imo.

Comment: Using 'net share' and properly configuring 'fstab' is high level and is the most maintainable way of completing this task. It's not 'hackish' at all. Welcome to network administration 101.